# Pass Network credentials to Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I face frequent disconnections on my application which connects to Docusign REST API using the Docusign SDK. The application runs in a windows VM , in which internet access is regulated through corporate proxy and firewall

To overcome this problem , I want to pass the network credentials to the Docusign SDK classes , so that the credentials be passed to RestRequest of RESTSharp. I can see the credentials property in RestSharp, but no equivalent method to pass the same to Docusign SDK.

Please help , anyone knows how to make this work in corporate proxy env?

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign Rest Api does not support windows authentication. See [this](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) for the various forms of authentication supported by DocuSign Rest API.

---

### Single SignOn

However DocuSign supports single sign-on with your organizations identity provider.

Here is the related documentation

[single-sign-on-implementation-guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/single-sign-on-implementation-guide) **PDF**

[single-sign-on-overview](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/single-sign-on-overview.htm)

---

## Video

Here is a cool [video](https://dev.docusign.com/developertrack/authenticating-with-docusigns-api-10) overview of the authentication mechanisms with docusign api.

Comment: Not an answer to my problem. Since my issue was on corporate proxy . But yes your answer helps to confirm Docusign Business functionality